# Error found when loading /etc/profile.d/maven.sh: line 1 when starting laptop

Tags: maven-3

when i start my laptop, i get the following error message:

Error found when loading /etc/profile.d/maven.sh: line 1:[200~export: command not found

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N63LJ.png)

Can someone please provide me with a solution? it seems to be a unique problem and I could not find any solution on this site or anywhere. Unique in the sense, I have not seen anywhere else that it says it has an error at "line 1".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. It would have been quite easy to have entered that short bit of text into the body of the question.

Comment: What you have here is not the complete error.

Comment: You could just open the file and delete the extra nonsense characters

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh`.

Comment: @user253751 Until you've seen a `cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh` you're just guessing.

Comment: thank you guys. I have decided to reinstall everything and i am having trouble just installing maven first. I created a post about this :): 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402793/tmp-scheme-missing-same-error-even-when-i-create-a-tmp-folder-what-exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the contents of the file `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh`.
If you created it yourself, remove the garbage characters `[200~` from the beginning of the file and check whether the remainder of the file has any more garbage sprinkled into it. If it came with some package you installed, reconfigure or reinstall that package.

Comment: Until you've seen a `cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh` you're just guessing.

Comment: I disagree. The error message clearly says the file starts with `[200~export`. I needn't see the whole file to conclude that's bad.

Comment: Yes, I agree that doesn't look good. But what if there's more wrong than just that small part? You don't know until you look.

Comment: That's why I wrote: "and check the remainder of the file."

Comment: Sigh. OP has only been a user here for 2 days, and I strongly suspect that they don't know what to look for, otherwise they could have already fixed this themselves. It's **our** job to look at the file and see what's actually wrong with it, without making guesses.

Comment: thank you guys. I have decided to reinstall everything and i am having trouble just installing maven first. I created a post about this :): 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402793/tmp-scheme-missing-same-error-even-when-i-create-a-tmp-folder-what-exactly

Comment: that was it. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

The first line of your script should specify the interpreter for the script, using the `#!` convention. If the first line isn't  something like.

`#!/bin/bash`

an old interpreter, `/bin/sh`, is used. `/bin/sh` doesn't understand `export`.

Put the above code before your `export`.

Comment: What is "your script" in this context? `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh` is getting *sourced* by a login shell here I think? In any case, what happens when a script lacks a shebang is rather more complicated - see [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373294/65304)

Comment: ... as well, `/bin/sh` certainly understands `export` - in fact it's part of the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export). What you may be recalling is that the *original* Bourne shell didn't support export-assignments like `export var=value` which were therefore usually written as `var=value; export var` - see [Where is "export var=value" not available?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available)

Comment: Until you've seen a `cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh` you're just guessing.

Comment: The files in `/etc/profile.d` don't and shouldn't start with a `#!` interpreter specification. They are not scripts which can be executed directly, but included/sourced by other scripts.

Comment: thank you guys. I have decided to reinstall everything and i am having trouble just installing maven first. I created a post about this :): 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402793/tmp-scheme-missing-same-error-even-when-i-create-a-tmp-folder-what-exactly