# /tmp: Scheme missing, same error even when I create a "tmp" folder. What exactly is the problem and how do I fix this?

Tags: tmp, maven-3, opt, scheme

so i am trying install maven following the steps on this website for "Step 2: Download and Install Maven": https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-maven-on-ubuntu

and i get the following error: [/tmp: Scheme missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsXq1.jpg)

I get the same error even when I create a "tmp" folder.

i get the same error for the extraction in the /opt directory.

Can someone tell me what exactly the problem is and how do I fix this?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: You appear to have missed the `-P` switch in your `wget` command (`wget  ... -P /tmp` ); so `wget` thinks `/tmp` is another URL (one for which it doesn't have a "scheme" for downloading).

Comment: thank you ! i also had to open the terminal from "Computer". By default the terminal was connected to the "Home" directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have your syntax wrong. See `man wget`. You do not specify a destination directory by supplying a second argument. You do that with the `-P` option.

While multiple arguments can be provided, these should be valid URL's which then will be downloaded in sequence. `/tmp` is not a valid url, hence the error message.

Thus, `-P /tmp` rather than `/tmp` alone would have redirected the download to that directory instead of the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to open the terminal from "Computer". By default, the terminal was connected to the "Home" directory, but the "/tmp" und "/opt" directories are in the "Computer" directory.

Comment: Hello. There is no directory called computer. Could you please make this answer clear.

Comment: It is probably for you the "C:/" Drive, where you will the find the folder like tmp and opt. In my case, its called "Computer".

Comment: These are windows terms. Never used in Ubuntu. Are you even using Ubuntu it is not mentioned in your question.